# .jar file not working outside of eclipse

Tags: permissions, java, eclipse

I have a basic log recorder program that I like to use to record stuff that I do. It's a pretty basic program coded in Java with a GUI that has three text boxes to enter directory, file name and text you'd like to record. I had been using it on Windows prettily. Now that I've gotten tired of instability of Windows I installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried running the program on Ubuntu. It stated something about giving app permission. I did do that by getting to its properties. I ran my program, but when I entered my text and pressed enter, no file had been created or edited. I had the source code on Pastebin so copied it over to Eclipse to check for compatibility. The directories it seems doesn't work the same way as it is in Windows. Well, removed that part and the app now produces text files as I want it to in the directory it's working on (eg. workspace of Eclipse). It works prettily.

But when I export the program into a .jar file and put it in my documentaries, it asks for permission once again. I did give it an execution privilege once again from properties. The program, just as the old version, runs prettily. Except it can't create nor edit .txt files.

I thought it was a problem about permissions. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that's why it didn't produce any errors. Remember how I told you that the directories were working differently from Windows? It seems the OS takes Home as the beginning path and not the location where the program is located in. Therefore it created all the files in Home folder. I don't know how to handle the directory issue, yet. But it's good to know the program is actually working.

Thank you, people anyway.

Edit: Also, it seems it's easy as replacing backslashes with forward ones to optimise the directory checking to Linux.